# Entity Framework Core to Json Ignore ReferenceLoop - Parent Child

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I having entity class with parent-child relationship that having problem serializing to json using newtonsoft json.net

```
public class Department
{        
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }          
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }       
    public Department Parent { get; set; }          
    public ICollection<Department> Children { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

While i'm expecting a json format such as this.

```
[
  {
    "departmentId": 1,   
    "title":        "Finance",
    "children": [
      {
        "departmentId": 2,        
        "title":        "Accounting",
        "children": [
          {
            "departmentId": 3,            
            "title":        "Payable"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But the result i get this Stackoverflow Exception from http-repl
[image: Stackoverflow exception]

I trying using Ignore ReferenceLooping, this doesn't solve the stackoverflow problem i have

```
services.AddMvc()
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
       options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    })
```

Here is the Controller, if you are asking;

```
//GET: api/Department
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Department>>> GetDepartments()
{
    var result = await _context.Departments
        .Include(department => department.Children)
        .Where(department => department.ParentId == null)
        .ToListAsync();
    return Ok(result);
}
```

- Reference [Loading Related Data with Include()](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14147)
- Github commit [a5d4a3d](https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/commit/9ca3b16752409cd153a33260cc39cbeb0c8e9149)

I have tried Data Transfer Object (DTO) still not working.

## Update 29 Dec 2018

Let set this up correctly, you can clone base project at https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/tree/base. Then you can add the database in the following path `src\Organization.WebApi`

```
dotnet ef migrations add init
dotnet ef database update
```

This will give you at seed data for Department with following data

[image: Department Seed Data]

From the seed Data, the maximum child we will have only 3 level deep and no circle release as infinite loop.

- A > B > C

So we don't see A > B > A infinite loop here in this seed data.

After this we can doing debug using [dotnet-httprepl](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/http-repl-tool-to-test-web-api-in-asp-net-core-2-2/) and we should the same results.
[image: StackOverFlow]

Now lets [comment out all methods](https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/tree/RefLoop/Base) in the department controller to limited the error scope. Then we get the http-repl up and running.

[image: https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/tree/bases/refactor]

So let just [enable get all departments](https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/tree/RefLoop/GetAll) and see what entity framework returns;

[image: Department with no parent as root departments]

But this produce json serialization error for http-repl, maybe from swagger ui json `http://localhost:56739/swagger/v1/swagger.json`

[image: Stackoverflow by enabling get all]

[Lets add `\[JsonIgnore\]` to the Site & Parent](https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/tree/RefLoop/ignoreParent) then rerun the http-repl

```
public class Department
{        
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Department Parent { get; set; }          
    public ICollection<Department> Children { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Still its produce the same error

[image: Evening ignore the parent]

So now [let Ignore all relationship](https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/tree/RefLoop/IgnoreAll) to serialize json to see if we can get all departments. But this produce departments without its children, which is not we are expecting the correct results.

```
public class Department
{        
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Site Site { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Department Parent { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public ICollection<Department> Children { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

[image: get all departments but without the children]

Comment: Show your controller method code please!

Comment: did you use AutoMapper?

Comment: @TanvirArjel have a look https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/blob/dev/src/Organization.WebApi/Controllers/DepartmentController.cs

Comment: @AliTooshmalani Yes, I have tried AutoMapper

Comment: @SarinNaWangkanai Please check my answer and let me know if it works! If not then tell me the problem please!

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Department>>> GetDepartments()
        {
            var result = await _context.Departments
                .Include(department => department.Children)
                .Where(department => department.ParentId == null)
                .ToListAsync();
            return Ok(result);
        }

Comment: @TanvirArjel I have add the controller in the question as requested.

Comment: @tanvirarjel you can just clone the whole project from github at https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization

Comment: @SarinNaWangkanai Then I have to set up database, have to insert test values to database etc. If you have problem then its okay.

Comment: I suggest you check whether there is any durty data in the database. I clone your project and run it, it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised it's throwing *that* exception, since usually Json.NET will catch a circular reference before a StackOverflow happens. But it's still possible that it's the circular reference that's killing it. (It's trying to serialize the `Parent`, then looking at the `Children` of that, then looking at the `Parent` of each of those, etc.)

You could modify your model to tell the serialization to ignore the `Parent`:

```
public class Department
{        
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }          
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public Department Parent { get; set; }          
    public ICollection<Department> Children { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried AutoMapper https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/commit/8d99967a1ea3fb7fd0f8925f7110aca177d191c8

Comment: Add `[JsonIgnore]` on `Parent` doesn't help and if I add `[JsonIgnore]` on `Children` then it doesn't produce the children.

Comment: If ignoring `Children` makes it complete (but without children) that means there is a circular reference in your `Children` (a department has a child that is also a parent of itself). It could even be a few levels deep, something like: A -> B -> C -> A. That will cause it to loop infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to convert DTO just to get json format as you have got EF Code first model which I can see

```
    public class Department
    {        
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }          
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }       
    public Department Parent { get; set; }          
    public ICollection<Department> Children { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

You can directly return json output as following way from your action controller.

```
     public class JsonDemoController : Controller  
     {  
        #region ActionControllers  

         /// <summary>  
        /// Get department data in Json Format  
        /// </summary>  
        /// <returns></returns> 

        public JsonResult GetDepartmentJsonData()  
        {  
            var departments= GetDepartments();  
            return Json(departments, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
        }


        private List<Department> GetDepartments()  
        {  
            var departmentList = new List<Department>  
            {  
                new Department  
                {  
                    DepartmentId = 1,  
                    Title = "Finance",  
                    Children = childrenCollection
                }  

            };  

            return departmentList;  
        }     
     }
```

I have not tested on IDE though let me know if any issue on code.

Comment: I have tried that DTO even create a mapper manually at https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/commit/a5d4a3d5c11ba1ae533056e7b17b35a1b979a7ab before i trying AutoMapper at https://github.com/wangkanai/Organization/commit/8d99967a1ea3fb7fd0f8925f7110aca177d191c8 My head has been spinning around a few days now.